# Scifi story about a world with a portal in the center (things fall off the side and reappear in the center); materials with light-to-thrust ratios

Tags: story-identification, books

I was chatting to a friend-of-a-friend in a bar and he mentioned a series of books that he was reading. I wanted to read the series, but I cannot remember the name of the book, and I have not been able to get in contact with him.

What I can remember:

- The world is a disc; anything that falls off the edge reappears in a portal and drops down into the center of the world.
- There is material that will be fixed in space if it is in darkness. One can shift some of this material into the air, then encase it in concrete, and it will create a floating island which one can create buildings on.
- There are other materials which produce thrust if light is shone on them. I vaguely remember that one can make flying objects by shining a bright light at the material.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did your friend first tell you about these books?

Comment: @LogicDictates 2022, he mentioned it was a relatively recent series.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may be *Shadow of the Conqueror* by Shad M. Brooks, published in 2019. It is the first book in a projected series called *Chronicles of Everfall*, though no other books have been released yet.

> There is material that will be fixed in space if it is in darkness. One can shift some of this material into the air, then encase it in concrete, and it will create a floating island which one can create buildings on.

The material is called "darkstone", and the floating continents in the setting are supported by it. I have no idea if the people in the setting have invented concrete or not, but they are certainly aware of darkstone's properties.

> There are other materials which produce thrust if light is shone on them. I vaguely remember that one can make flying objects by shining a bright light at the material.

This is another property of darkstone. There are airships in the setting that use this method for propulsion.

> The world is a disc; anything that falls off the edge reappears in a portal and drops down into the center of the world.

This is a little garbled, but it's a rough fit for how the setting works.

- The world is made up of floating continents and islands in the middle of the air. There's no disc per se, but it is a "flat" world compared to our own.
- Anything that falls out of the "bottom" of the world (well below the continents) will reappear at the "top", still falling. There are no portals per se, it's just that space is warped so that everything wraps around. If you look up, very far above you, you can see the bottom of the continent that you are currently standing on.

---

I have not read the book myself. All my information comes from [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/ShadowOfTheConqueror) and [a Fandom wiki](https://chroniclesofeverfall.fandom.com/wiki/ChroniclesOfEverfall_Wiki).

Comment: This absolutely has to be it, I vaguely remember him mentioning Darkstone. This had been bothering me for 6 months, but problem solved, you are a legend! Thank you for the feeling of a solved rubix cube (albeit with an expert doing all the work!).